# Form with list of checkboxes (best practices)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, ienumerable

I have a view that allows the user to make a selection from an IEnumerable.
The way I'm doing it now is to give each checkbox the id of the item and work with the form collection at the controller's side.

I seem to remember there to be a better way but can't remember how anymore.
Are there any better practices?

Answer (score 1):

I did try that myself; I would append the ID to each check item, but a friend told me to do it as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" checked="<%= obj.Selected %>" 
value="<%= obj.Key %>" />
```

Then you can refer to chk in the form collection, and it would contain the array of keys for the objects selected.

Comment: Hmm, that would render my html invalid because they all have the same ID. Did you mean class="chk"?

Comment: He told me ID...  I admit, I didn't try it, but my friend is a good architect so I trusted his judgment.  Sorry for recommending something I didn't try :-)